# Why does mouse behavior differ in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, mouse, touchscreen

Why do the default mouse driver and settings feel different in Windows 8, as compared to Windows 7.  Is there is a way to make the mouse behave more like it did in Windows 7?

Others have [also noticed](http://www.overclock.net/t/1321857/windows-8-weird-mouse-feel-mad) this problem.

Comment: @avirk The question is tagged Windows 8.

Comment: What setting you are using at the moment? Post them in your post for help to understand the problem.

Comment: The mouse settings are identical between the windows 7 and windows 8 installations since they are both clean installs but the mouse feels different.  I'm guessing there was some change to the default mouse driver to have better touch support or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pointer speed in mouse properties->pointer options and adjust there. Also, try turning off "Enhance Pointer Precision"

Comment: Please see my comment in the question.